# Entity framework join based on Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm beginning out with asp.net mvc3 and mvc in general and I'm learning entity framework at the same time also.

The app i'm building allows users to create bills or payments for other users and I am unsure on how to create the relationships for the bill and account classes when writing my query. The issue i'm having is I am storing the accountId's in the database however I want to display the user's first and last name from the toAccountId and fromAccountId.

Classes

```
public class Bill
{
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public string BillName { get; set; }
    public string BillDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDue { get; set; }
    public int FromAccountId { get; set; }
    public int ToAccountId { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}

public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Bill> Bills { get; set; } 
}
```

In the controller

```
private IBillRepository repository;
public ViewResult Home()
{
    int userID = 1;
    HomeViewModel viewModel = new HomeViewModel
    {
        Bills = repository.Bills
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.DateCreated)
            .Where(b => b.FromAccountId.Equals(userID))
            .Take(amountOfBillsOnPageOnLoad)
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Any errors you are getting ? What is your question ?

Comment: Sorry i'm not actually getting any errors. Basically i'm trying to accomplish in my view instead of displaying an id(FromAccountId) it will display the name of the account. So i'm having issues setting up the relationship between FromAccountId/ToAccountId and AccountId

Comment: you might want to use the navigation property..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help // using the navigation property

```
public class Bill
{
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public string BillName { get; set; }
    public string BillDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDue { get; set; }
    public int FromAccountId { get; set; }
    public int ToAccountId { get; set; }

    public Account Accounts { get; set; }  // Navigation Property to the Account
}
```

in your view you can access the Account object properties like this.

```
@model.Accounts.FirstName
```

Comment: Thank you that was useful and put me on the right path. Will I need to re arrange my table structure since I need to have an AccountId in Bill(meaning I can't use fromAccountId)?

Comment: if you are storing accountID in Bill, then you can have that property in Bill and the navigation property of Account in Bill object so that you can use all of the Accounts object properties in Bill object. AND if you currently added fromAccountId for that purspose then you dont need that anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me quite a bit. After finding out the name of what I want to achieve I was able to research it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
 Bills = repository.Bills.Include("Account")
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.DateCreated)
            .Where(b => b.FromAccountId.Equals(userID))
            .Take(amountOfBillsOnPageOnLoad)
```

...should get you going. Note the use of 'Include' to pull data from related tables into the query. You can also use this syntax (probably preferred actually) `.Include(b => b.Account)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
  public class Bill
    {
        public int BillId { get; set; }
       //...........
        public Account FromAccount { get; set; }
        public Account ToAccount { get; set; }
        public int FromAccountId { get; set; }
        public int ToAccountId { get; set; }
    }


    public class Account
    {
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
     //..............
    }
```